# Symmetry of fractional laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fractional-calculus

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, let $s\in [1/2,1)$, let $u\in C^{1,2s-1+\epsilon}(\Omega)$ such that: $u=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$, and: $u\in C^{0,s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is true that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(-\Delta)^su\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(-\Delta)^s\phi,\quad\forall\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)?$$
I kwon only that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi(-\Delta)^sf\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(-\Delta)^s\phi\,dx,\quad\forall f,\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
I have no idea on how to go on, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The proof follows by approximation, but the correct setting is $u \in H^{2s}_0(\Omega)$. Whether your condition on $u$ implies that $u$ is in the Sobolev space $H^{2s}_0(\Omega)$ may depend on the exact definition of $C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$, as pointed out in many of your previous questions.

Comment: Can you give the details of this approximation in $H^{2s}(\Omega)$, please? I do not know any approximation results in  $H^{2s}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: Moreover, for $u\in C^{1,2s-1+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ i mean that: $u$ is $(2s-1+\epsilon)$-Hölder continuous and $\nabla u$ is  $(2s-1+\epsilon)$-Hölder continuous. This hypothesis implies that: $u\in H^{2s}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Any $H^{2s}(\mathbb R^n)$ function $u$ can be approximated by a sequence $u_n$ of Schwartz functions in the norm of $H^{2s}(\mathbb R^n)$ (so that $u_n$ converges to $u$ and $(-\Delta)^s u_n$ converges to $(-\Delta)^s u$, both limits in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$). This can be found in most textbooks on Sobolev spaces, I believe. I am sure it is proved in Samko's *Hypersingular integrals and Their Applications*.

Comment: Regarding your other comment: I already explained that some authors use $C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for the class of functions with $k$-th partial derivatives Hölder continuous in any compact subset of $\Omega$, while others require them to by Hölder continuous in all of $\Omega$. In the latter case, $u$ extends to a function in $C^{k,\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$, so with this definition the assumptions in your questions would be odd (if $u \in C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega)$, then automatically $y \in C^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb R^n)$).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki and so with my definition of $C^{1,2s+\epsilon-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ i can say that $u\in H^{2s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? I can't prove this fact. If you help me I am infinitely grateful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116297/discussion-between-inoc-and-mateusz-kwasnicki).

Comment: With my definition of $C^{1,2s+\epsilon-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i have that $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but $u=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$, with $\Omega$ open and bounded, then: $u\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. $u$ is the class $C^1$ with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this implies that: $u\in H^{2s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3):

If $x, y \in \Omega$, then
$$ |u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)| \leqslant C |y - x|^{2 s + \epsilon} ,$$
and so the integral
$$ \iint_{\Omega \times \Omega} \frac{u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy $$
converges absolutely.

Denote $d(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, \partial \Omega)$. If $x \in \Omega$, $y \in \Omega^c$, then $|u(x)| \leqslant C d(x)$ (because $\nabla f$ is bounded) and $u(y) = 0$. Thus,
$$ |u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)| \leqslant |u(x)| + |\nabla u(x)| \, |y - x| \leqslant C d(x) + C |y - x| .$$
Furthermore,
$$ \int_{\Omega^c} \frac{1}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, dy \leqslant \frac{1}{(d(x))^{2s}} $$
and
$$ \int_{\Omega^c} \frac{|y - x|}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, dy \leqslant \frac{1}{(d(x))^{2s - 1}} \, . $$
Finally, $1 / (d(x))^{2s - 1}$ is integrable. It follows that the integral
$$ \iint_{\Omega \times \Omega^c} \frac{u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy $$
converges absolutely, too.

Similarly, if $x \in \Omega^c$ and $y \in \Omega$, we find that
$$ |u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)| \leqslant |u(y)| \leqslant C d(y) ,$$
and since
$$ \int_\Omega \frac{1}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, dy \leqslant \min \biggl\{ \frac{1}{(d(x))^{2s}} , \frac{C |\Omega|}{|x|^{n + 2 s}} \biggr\} , $$
we have absolute convergence of
$$ \iint_{\Omega^c \times \Omega} \frac{u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy . $$

Finally, the integral over $\Omega^c \times \Omega^c$ is identically zero.

---

We conclude that the integral
$$ \iint_{\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n} \frac{u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy $$
converges absolutely. Now the usual argument applies:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_\Omega (-\Delta)^s u(x) \phi(x) dx
 & = \iint_{\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n} \frac{u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy \\
 & =  \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \iint_{|x - y| > \delta} \frac{u(y) - u(x) - \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy \\
 & =  \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \iint_{|x - y| > \delta} \frac{u(y) - u(x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, \phi(x) dx dy \\
 & =  \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \iint_{|x - y| > \delta} \frac{\phi(y) - \phi(x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, u(x) dx dy \\
 & =  \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \iint_{|x - y| > \delta} \frac{\phi(y) - \phi(x) - \nabla \phi(x) (y - x)}{|y - x|^{n + 2 s}} \, u(x) dx dy \\
 & = \int_\Omega (-\Delta)^s \phi(x) u(x) dx .
\end{aligned}$$
(Here the second equality follows by dominated convergence, the fourth one by Fubini, and the sixth one again by dominated convergence.)

Comment: Regarding the integral expression for $(-\Delta)^s u(x)$: isn't this the very definition of $(-\Delta)^s u(x)$? The term $|y - x|^{-n - 2s} \nabla u(x) \cdot (y - x)$ disappears because it has zero integral over $\mathbb R^n \setminus B(x, r)$ for every $r > 0$.

Comment: (The above comment answers questions raised in other comments that now seem deleted.)